# Are spherical harmonics harmonic?

Tags: harmonic-functions, laplacian, spherical-harmonics

According to Wikipedia, a harmonic function is one which satisfies:
$$
\nabla^2 f = 0
$$
The spherical harmonics (also according to Wikipedia) satisfy the relation
$$
\nabla^2 Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) = -\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
which is 0 only if $l = 0$. So by this definition, are the spherical harmonic functions only harmonic when $l,m = 0$?

As a related question, if I change coordinates to some $\alpha(\theta,\phi), \beta(\theta,\phi)$ and I want to find the orthogonal functions similar to the spherical harmonics in the new $\alpha,\beta$ basis, how would I do that? Would I need to solve Laplace's equation
$$
\nabla^2_{\alpha,\beta} f(\alpha,\beta) = 0
$$
where $\nabla^2_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the Laplacian expressed in the new coordinate system?

Comment: why did u ask $m=0$? isn't $l=0$ enough?

Comment: @mathworker21 $|m| \leq l$, so $l = 0$ implies $m=0$. So not necessary to say $m=0$, but no loss of generality either.

Answer (score 14):

There is more than one Laplacian $\Delta=\nabla^2$ in play here: the ambient Euclidean one, and the invariant Laplacian on the sphere. The "spherical harmonics" extended in the natural way as polynomials, are harmonic for the ambient Euclidean space. They are *eigenfunctions* for the Laplacian on the sphere, with (generally) non-zero eigenvalues for that operator.

Yes, there is some connection between the two, which can be found in many places...

Answer (score 11):

The spherical harmonics are restrictions to the unit sphere of harmonic functions on $\mathbb R^3$.  There are no non-constant harmonic functions on the sphere itself.

Comment: +1 And no non-constant harmonic functions on any compact manifold https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3638457/532409