# Given a smooth function, does there exist a (semi-)Riemannian metric for which it is harmonic?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

To be precise: given $\phi \in C^{\infty}(M)$, does there exist a (semi-)Riemannian metric $g$ such that $\Delta_{g}\phi = 0$?

I avoided fixing a coordinate system on purpose here; I'm not sure how that would come into play, but I expect it might.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638437/why-is-there-no-harmonic-function-on-compact-riemannian-manifold

Comment: @mfl I am not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @Stańczyk Choose a nonconstant function on a compact manifold. It will not be harmonic w.r.t. any metric.

Comment: @Kajelad  Of course this true of a Riemannian metric. More generally?

Comment: Even if one allows for a metric of any signature, there will still be counterexamples (e.g. $S^2$, which admits no indefinite nondegenerate metrics due to the hairy ball theorem). Determining if such a metric exists when $M$ *does* admit an indefinite metrics might be difficult, though.