# Reference to statement: A harmonic function on a compact connected riemannian manifold is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-functions, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

I read this statement a few times, for example [in the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638437/why-must-harmonic-functions-on-compact-riemannian-manifolds-be-constant). Does anyone have a reference to this statement?

Comment: What’s wrong with the proof given by Ivo?

Comment: well he relies on "Stokes' theorem says that the integral of a divergence (hence of a Laplacian) over a compact manifold without boundary vanishes" which he does not proof. also he assumes that M is oriented as pointed out by "Quarto Bendir". So I would like to see a formal proof listing all assumptions etc.

Comment: I have two comments to that. First, the divergence theorem does not require an orientation. People often formulate it as a corollary of Stokes’ theorem (which does require an orientation), but you don’t need to. For a reference, see Loomis and Sternberg’s [Advanced Calculus](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf), chapter 10.6. Second, on a compact boundaryless manifold, the boundary terms vanish so that part is trivial, so you should really just review the usual Stokes/divergence theorems.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for your comments. I suppose what was confusing me then is that we can simply apply the divergence theorem for a manifold without a boundary although the divergence theorem is always stated for a manifold with a boundary. In that sense, a manifold without boundary is a manifold with the empty set as boundary and thus the integral vanishes?

Comment: Yes that’s correct. But really if you analyze the proof of the theorem, you see that it is often split into two cases, one where the function/form has support not intersecting the boundary (which includes the case of empty boundary) and the other case where it does intersect the boundary. You can see that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341695/568204) (but note that my proof there requires one extra degree of differentiability than what I stated, but the theorem statement is still correct lol… but you’re dealing with $C^{\infty}$ so you can ignore these remarks).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! Feel free to post your reference to Loomis and Sterberg as an asnwer.

Comment: You can answer your own question.